# Why move node_modules to parent directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules

In the Docker extension for Visual Studio Code, in the Node.js Dockerfile template, the node_modules directory is moved to the parent directory, in [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/blob/018c92815ff2eeed50ec9e9af1d842ebf7a7a329/resources/templates/node/Dockerfile.template#L5):

```
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
```

The `mv node_modules ../` looks useless to me.
Is there a reason to do that?

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE:** [found a good explanation](https://www.docker.com/blog/keep-nodejs-rockin-in-docker/) of the "why". See: the section on *Dealing With Node Modules*.

**TLDR;** lets you run the app in and out of the container without worry that the OS-specific items in node_modules will not work between the host and the container.

**Original (wrong as pointed out in the comments) answer:**

This is to take advantage of the caching mechanism in Docker.  Typically you'll have the following in your `Dockerfile`:

```
1. RUN apt-get #bunch of stuff you want installed
2. COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
3. RUN npm install --silent && mv node_modules ../
4. COPY . .
5. CMD node index.js
```

Docker builds its images in "layers", you can think of each layer being added as each line in the `Dockerfile` is executed.

Then what we are saying in snipped above is:

1. Run `apt-get` and commit the layer to the cache
2. Next, copy the `package.json` file from the host to the container, commit the layer
3. Run `npm install`, then move the `node_modules` folder up one directory, `npm` will recursively search upward until it finds an `node_modules folder`, so your app won't care. Commit this layer.
4. Copy your source code contained in the current folder, to the container, commit this layer
5. Finally, when your container is run, use the command `node index.js`

The beauty of this system is that Docker will re-build a container only from the point where things have changed since the last time the container was built.  So in our case, it'll only run `npm install…` if the previous layer had changes, say an updated `package.json`.  If not, then it won't execute the `npm install` command, even if, say, `index.js` might have changed.

Of course, keep in mind you should have `node_modules` listed in your `.dockerignore` file so that the `COPY . .` doesn't try to pick it up.

Comment: My question is *why* the `mv node_modules ../` part? I understand how it works, but would like to know why it was done that way. Why move node_modules up a directory? Why not have just `RUN npm install --production --silent` and leave node_modules as is?

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't actually answer the question that's been asked.

Comment: @TheBrenny how does it not?

Comment: @ThaDon it answers why Docker creates sub-containers to build upon. It also answers how Node searches for `require`d modules, but the question is asking *why* the modules are moved up. What's the difference between `npm install` and `npm install && mv node_modules ../` in the context of the docker container - as in what's the benefit of moving the modules upward instead of leaving them there?

Comment: @TheBrenny I thought I was pretty clear when I said that by doing so, changes to index.js will then not trigger a full npm install… If you leave node_modules where it is, anytime you change your code then Docker will have to run that command.

Comment: That's not accurate. Changes to index.js don't trigger npm install because `RUN npm install` is before `COPY . .`.  Moving node_modules is still useless to me.

Comment: @nuno Updated the answer, you were right in that `npm install` will not have been triggered by updates to index.js. Instead the `mv node_modules ../` is used to allow for running the app inside and outside of the container (i.e. OS-specific dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented why the did it, but you can move `node_modules` up, such that when you create a bind mount — like a Dev Container for example does — you do not have to `npm i` again for example in the `postStartCommand` in the case of a Dev Container. I say `npm i` again, because you already did it in the `Dockerfile` there, or they did it. Note, that you cannot just reuse the node_modules from the host within your Docker Container via the bind mount, because the binaries are not compatible if you for example run Windows on the host and the Container runs Debian.

But moving it one directory up only, does not make that much sense in my opinion, it makes more sense to move it to `/`, because a Dev Container for example lives in `/workspaces` and it would not see `/usr/src/node_modules` in this particular case that you linked.

Sidenote: In the case of a Dev Container you also want to create a named or anonymous volume for `${containerWorkspaceFolder}/node_modules`, because otherwise when you install some package via `npm` you would also write to the host filesystem due to the bind mount.

I hope that gives you a better idea why they maybe did it.